# Can not pass arguments from shell script to Perl script

Tags: linux, bash, perl, shell

I have the next shell script which I have named `run.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#!/bin/sh

BROL="/sc01a4/users/user/brol"
PID=$$

while read line
do
  echo "$line" >> $BROL/rolak/1_EUSLEM_MATE/Sarrera_Testua_$PID.xml
done < "${1:-/proc/${$}/fd/0}"

perl $BROL/rolak/NAGUSIA.pl $BROL $PID
```

This script runs `NAGUSIA.pl` with two arguments, the path `BROL` and the process id, variable `PID`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

my $direktorioa = "$ARGV[0]";
my $prozesua = "$ARGV[1]";

use lib "$direktorioa/rolak/lib";
use SRL::NAGUSIA qw(Egokitu_Sarrera Predikatu_Identifikazioa Predikatu_Desanbiguazioa Argumentuak_Identifikatu Argumentuak_Sailkatu Sortu_Irteera);

Egokitu_Sarrera($prozesua, $direktorioa);
Predikatu_Identifikazioa($prozesua, $direktorioa);
Predikatu_Desanbiguazioa($prozesua, $direktorioa);
Argumentuak_Identifikatu($prozesua, $direktorioa);
Argumentuak_Sailkatu($prozesua, $direktorioa);
Sortu_Irteera($prozesua, $direktorioa);
```

The Perl script is supposed two receive these two arguments but the command line gives the next error:

```
Use of uninitialized value $direktorioa in concatenation (.) or string at /sc01a4/users/user/brol/rolak/NAGUSIA.pl line 9.
```

I use the next command in order to run the shell script:

```
cat brol/proba_fitxategiak/proba4.txt | sh brol/EHU-eustagger/run.sh | sh brol/rolak/run.sh
```

I am using Linux, not Windows. Why the Perl script does not receive the arguments passed by the shell script?

Comment: That's not the problem and perl script does receive the value. Put a print at line 7. `print "direktorioa : $direktorioa \n";` to verify that.

Comment: I put the print but it is ignored and the error from line 9 persists.

Comment: What's with the perl shebang in run.sh?

Comment: Naming all your shell programs `run.sh` won't help you to find errors.

Comment: *"I put the print but it is ignored"* I suspect that you are editing the wrong `run.sh`. That is a result of having at least two programs called `run.sh` and possibly more.

Answer (score 5):

`use` statements are executed at compile-time, so

```
use lib "$direktorioa/rolak/lib";
```

is executed before

```
my $direktorioa = "$ARGV[0]";
```

Replace

```
use lib "$direktorioa/rolak/lib";
```

with

```
use lib "$ARGV[0]/rolak/lib";
```

That said, you should really be using the following anyway:

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
use lib "$RealBin/lib";
```